# Update - Where Clause Using Text Not Responding As Expected

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains a column named 'time_source', with five potential values:

'model', 'country_city', 'region', 'update', and 'storage'

I've been attempting to make an update statement that will not update column date_destination if the time_source is 'model' like this:

```
update t_vessel_list_ballast
set date_destination = date_depart + voyage_time
where time_source not like 'model';
```

But it isn't working as i'd expect. instead, it's overwriting the date_destination even when 'model' is in the time_source. I tried something like this:

```
update t_vessel_list_ballast
set date_destination = date_depart + voyage_time
where time_source like 'country_city'
or time_source like 'region';
```

but i'm still getting the same results.

There is no other place in the model where this could be happening.

Why am i not getting the result i'm expecting? How do i solve this to get what I want?

Comment: Are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `like` operator in proper way? Usually it used with patterns: `... where time_source not like '%model%'` or something like this.

Comment: What datatype is your variable? If it's `char(n)`, it could be a problem, because Postgres adds some trailing spaces to match the length `n`. So you could try to cast your variable to `text` like `time_source::text` which should eliminate the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think with `like`, if you want to match rows (or not match rows like you do here), you'll also need `%`s on the pattern to show where to match any other characters. For example `like '%match'` will match any string ending with `match`, and `like 'match%'` will match strings starting with match. You can also combine them to match a string containing match with `like '%match%'`.

Comment: Actually, `'model'` is a pattern that only matches `'model'`.